# Bootstrap image issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, themes

I'm trying to add the image unikafront.jpg on the right-hand side of the page.  For some reason, the image is not displayed. Please note this section used to have a contact form which I removed to make space for the image. This is the bootstrap theme being used: http://authenticgoods.co/wrapbootstrap/themes/sparks/

```
<!-- contact section begins -->
<section id="contact-section">
 <div class="container contact-section">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-4 col-xs-12 contact-info">
      <h3>Contact Info</h3>
      <p><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> 101 some street  </p>
      <p><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i> Monday - Friday 9AM - 7PM PST</p>
      <p><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> <a href="mailto:info@domain.com?Subject=site" target="_top">info@domain.com</a></p>
      <p><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i> <a href="http://www.domain.com">www.domain.com</a></p>
       <h3>We love what we do and we’d love to talk with you about how we can help you grow your business!</h3>
        <div class="social-icons">
          <a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a><br>
          <a href="terms.html">Terms of Use</a><br>
          <a href="disclaimers.html">Disclaimers</a><br>
          <a href="compensation.html">Compensation Disclosure</a><br>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-5 col-xs-12">


        <img src="images/unikafront.jpg alt="" />



    </div>
  </div><!-- End row -->
</div>
```

Comment: You're missing the closing `"` on the `src` attribute. Should be `<img src="images/unikafront.jpg" alt="" />`

Answer (score 0):

Please close the src="" attribute like

```
 <img src="images/unikafront.jpg" alt="" />
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  The issue continues after fixing that though.

Comment: use the correct image extension (like: .png, .jpg , .gif)

Answer (score 0):

As i test it with the firebug tool with your relevant theme "sparks".
when i placed the image tag like

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/" alt="" />
```

it display the image without any problem. Kindly cross check that you are referring the correct path for the image in your `src` attribute.

Comment: Problem solved!  Thanks for helping me out.  Is there a way I can rate your answer?  I'm new here...